# React Native webview when does not have internet

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to make when the webview does not have internet display a message that does not have internet. I searched for things about it and did not find it. Can someone help me ? Sorry, I'm new with react-native.

> EDIT 1

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, NetInfo } from 'react-native';
import WebViewComp from './web_view_comp.js'

export default class App extends Component {
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
        connection_Status : ""
      }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
          'connectionChange',
          this._handleConnectivityChange
      );
      NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {
        if(isConnected == true){
          this.setState({connection_Status : "Online"})
        }
        else{
          this.setState({connection_Status : "Offline"})
        }
      });
    }


componentWillUnmount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      'connectionChange',
      this._handleConnectivityChange
  );
}

_handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
  if(isConnected == true){
      this.setState({connection_Status : "Online"})
    }
    else{
      this.setState({connection_Status : "Offline"})
    }
};


render() {
      if (this.state.connection_Status == "Online") {
         return (
            <WebViewComp/>
         )
      } else {
         return (
            <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
               <Text style={{fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 20}}> Você está { this.state.connection_Status }</Text>
            </View>
         )
      }
   }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   MainContainer: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
     padding: 20
   },

   TextStyle: {
     fontSize:20,
     textAlign: 'center',
   }

 });

`
```

I edited the code according to the help and I came to this result, however I believe that if the person has mobile internet connected and has no mobile data can have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use React Native [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo) here's an example from the docs:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
  console.log('First, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
});
function handleFirstConnectivityChange(isConnected) {
  console.log('Then, is ' + (isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline'));
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
    'connectionChange',
    handleFirstConnectivityChange
  );
}
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
  'connectionChange',
  handleFirstConnectivityChange
);
```

If you want to check for an specific URL you could send a request and update the state

let req = await fetch('https://www.someurl.com');
let isConnected = req.status === 200;

Comment: how can I show an error page using netinfo? and I think to remove it if someone activates the internet.

Comment: is there any way I can tell if a url is active, for example a ping. in the same webview url?

Comment: to check for connectivity in general here's an example https://reactnativecode.com/netinfo-example-to-detect-internet-connection/ using NetInfo

Comment: to check for an specific URL you can use fetch, I'm going to add it to the response

Comment: you could turn off the connection in the simulator to try it

Answer (score 4):

You can use `onError` event of `WebView` like this:

```
//declarations and imports
state={isError:false}
render(){
   return(
       <WebView onError={()=>alert("Something went wrong")} />
       )}
```

If you want to know if there is an internet or not you keep track of error from `onError`.

Comment: While researching on the subject I found this [link](https://medium.com/dailyjs/offline-notice-in-react-native-28a8d01e8cd0) where there is used Netinfo how could I use this with the onerror?

Comment: OnError is not calling in offline mode

Answer (score 0):

WebView of react-native have a props call `onMessage`, you can use that for know what url response when you dont have internet.

```
onWebViewMessage(event: any) {
   let msgData;
    try {
        // msgData will have the url from webview
        // and event have another props
        msgData = event.nativeEvent.data;
        // check and do something
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        return;
     }
     ...
}


<WebView
    source={{ uri: "http://www.youtube.com/" }}
    onMessage={this.onWebViewMessage}
    ...
 />
```

I hope help you, i dont remember exactly how to use that, but i think this a good way to start

Comment: Thank you, but I do not think I could do it this way.